# data.table doubles in size after being written

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the SALES dataset and a trimmed copy of it (TEST). The problem I have is that the SALES file doubles its value when it is saved.

This occurs only with this file (SALES), when the same procedure is performed with the TEST file, the result has the same size as the original file.

I tried transforming the file to an R base data frame and the result is still the same.

Similarly, if I open the file SALES_2 and save it, the size of this file doubles again.

This is the current code:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(stringi)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
options(scipen = 999)

SALES <- read_delim("C:/Users/edjca/OneDrive/FORMA/PRUEBA/SALES.csv", 
                      delim = "|", escape_double = FALSE, locale = 
                     locale(decimal_mark = ",",  grouping_mark ="."), trim_ws = TRUE)

TEST <- read_delim("C:/Users/edjca/OneDrive/FORMA/PRUEBA/Test.csv", 
                      delim = "|", escape_double = FALSE, 
                   locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = "."), trim_ws = TRUE)

data.table::fwrite(SALES, "C:/Users/edjca/OneDrive/FORMA/PRUEBA/SALES_2.csv", sep = "|", dec = ",")
data.table::fwrite(TEST, "C:/Users/edjca/OneDrive/FORMA/PRUEBA/Test_2.csv", sep = "|", dec = ",")
```

Add a picture of the results in my folder and objects sizes in R

[image: This is a picture of the results]

[image]

Comment: If you open `SALES` and `SALES2` in a text editor (or maybe just view the head and tail of the files) are there any obvious differences? More decimal places, maybe a date changes to a datetime, etc.?

Comment: Could it be that mixed type columns are forced to character once read_delim operates and thus creates a "larger" structure?

Comment: Is literally the same file, i cant find any difference between them